# How to use input mask with WTForms

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I'm developing a web platform that uses flask, sqlalchemy and wtforms to create some register and login pages, I have some FlaskForms using WTForms to create some input fields. I've been searching but I couldn't find how to use input mask with wtforms e.g. phone number +0 (00) 0 00000-000.

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, DataRequired, Length


class CreateAccount(FlaskForm):
    telefone = TextField('Telefone',id='telefone_id',validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For future developers that are searching for this, I've solved with jQuery.

https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/PbOEqL

Code

```
$(":input").inputmask();

$("#phone").inputmask({"mask": "(999) 999-9999"});
```